# SQL Server split SELECT XML column as arbitrary individual columns

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, dynamic-sql

In my application, I have few pre-defined fields for an object and user can define custom fields. I am using XML data type to store the custom fields in a name value format.

e.g. I have Employees table that has FN, LN, Email as pre-defined columns and CustomFields as XML column to hold the user defined fields.

And different rows can contain different custom fields.

e.g. Row 1 -> John, Smith, jsmith@example.com,

```
<root>
    <phone>123-123-1234</phone>
    <country>USA</country>
</root>
```

and then Row 2 -> Smith, John, sjohn@example.com,

```
<root>
    <age>50</age>
    <sex>Male</sex>
</root>
```

And there can be any number of such custom fields defined for different employee records. The format will always be the same

```
<root><field>value</field></root>
```

How can I return Phone and Country as columns while selecting Row1 and return Age and Sex as columns while selecting Row2?

Comment: Assuming I'm reading this correctly, I think you'd need dynamic SQL to produce the column names/values. e.g. `DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(4000) = ''; SELECT @cols += ', ''' + a.b.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(255)') + ''' AS ' + QUOTENAME(a.b.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(255)')) FROM myTable CROSS APPLY myXMLColumn.nodes('root/*') a(b) WHERE Email = 'jsmith@example.com';` then you'd create a dynamic SQL statement like `@SQL = 'SELECT fn, ln, email' + @cols + ' from myTable WHERE email = ''jsmith@example.com'';'; EXEC(@SQL);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this temp table for all examples

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (ID INT IDENTITY, FirstName VARCHAR(100),LastName VARCHAR(100),eMail VARCHAR(100),CustomFields XML);
INSERT INTO #tbl VALUES
 ('John','Smith','john.smith@test.com'
 ,'<root>
    <phone>123-123-1234</phone>
    <country>USA</country>
   </root>')
, ('Jane','Miller','jane.miller@test.com'
 ,'<root>
    <age>50</age>
    <sex>Male</sex>
   </root>');
```

### Option 1

- Assuming that there is a fix known set of custom fields.
- This allows typesafe reading (age as INT)
- all possible columns are returned, unused are NULL

Try this code

```
SELECT tbl.ID
      ,tbl.FirstName
      ,tbl.LastName
      ,tbl.eMail
      ,tbl.CustomFields.value('(/root/phone)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS phone
      ,tbl.CustomFields.value('(/root/country)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS country
      ,tbl.CustomFields.value('(/root/age)[1]','int') AS age
      ,tbl.CustomFields.value('(/root/sex)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS sex
FROM #tbl AS tbl
```

This is the result

```
+----+-----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+
| ID | FirstName | LastName | eMail                | phone        | country | age  | sex  |
+----+-----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+
| 1  | John      | Smith    | john.smith@test.com  | 123-123-1234 | USA     | NULL | NULL |
+----+-----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+
| 2  | Jane      | Miller   | jane.miller@test.com | NULL         | NULL    | 50   | Male |
+----+-----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+
*/
```

### Option 2

- assuming you do not know the field names in advance you cannot name the output columns directly
- But you can use generic names, read the data row-wise and do PIVOT

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.FirstName
          ,tbl.LastName
          ,tbl.eMail
          ,N'Col_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS ColumnName
          ,A.cf.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') + ':' +  A.cf.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS cf
    FROM #tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.CustomFields.nodes('/root/*') AS A(cf)  
) AS x
PIVOT
(
    MAX(cf) FOR ColumnName IN(Col_1,Col_2,Col_3,Col_4 /*add as many as you need*/)
) AS p
```

This is the result

```
+-----------+----------+----------------------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| FirstName | LastName | eMail                | Col_1              | Col_2       | Col_3 | Col_4 |
+-----------+----------+----------------------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| Jane      | Miller   | jane.miller@test.com | age:50             | sex:Male    | NULL  | NULL  |
+-----------+----------+----------------------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| John      | Smith    | john.smith@test.com  | phone:123-123-1234 | country:USA | NULL  | NULL  |
+-----------+----------+----------------------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+
```

### Option 3

- assuming you do not know the columns, but you need the columns correctly named
- **attention**: be aware of the fact, that such an approach will never be allowed in ad-hoc-SQL such as `VIEW` or `inline TVF` which might be a great back draw...

This needs dynamic creation of a statement. I will create the statement of Option 1 but replace the fix list with a dynamically created list:

```
DECLARE @DynamicColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT ',tbl.CustomFields.value(''(/root/' + A.cf.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') + ')[1]'',''nvarchar(max)'') AS ' +  A.cf.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM #tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.CustomFields.nodes('/root/*') AS A(cf)  
    FOR XML PATH('')
);

DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=
'   SELECT tbl.ID
      ,tbl.FirstName
      ,tbl.LastName
      ,tbl.eMail'
+ @DynamicColumns +
' FROM #tbl AS tbl;'

EXEC(@DynamicSQL);
```

The result would be the same as in Option 1, but with a completely dynamic approach.

Cleanup

```
DROP TABLE #tbl;
```